# SharePoint 2013 Pre-requisites failed to install app fabric

Tags: prerequisites, app-fabric

SharePoint 2013 Pre-requisites installation failed with error "Windows Server AppFabric: installation error"

After checking event logs, below error is logged.

"AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1605"

I have tried to install it manually using below command but it failed with same error.

prerequisiteinstaller.exe /AppFabric:prerequisiteinstallerfiles\AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe

Also checked the environment variable value and it is as below.

C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules

Even as suggested in few blogs checked for the groups AS_Observers and AS_Administrators and these groups does not exist.

Can someone suggest any other solution???

Comment: I had the same problem as OP. Spent days trying to find a fix. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling AppFabric via command line. It did not work for me. I then tried the PSModulePath solution that's been suggested everywhere. Did not work for me. At one point I realised I couldn't even install AppFabric at all (error code 1603) so I couldn't uninstall it either which is why a lot of the fixes weren't working. I must have stuffed something up from one of the fixes I found online. I don't know if that was your issue, but ultimately I started the installation from scratch again. It was faster. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running `AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe`, you should make sure that you have installed [WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/7/A678AB47-496B-4907-B3D4-0A2D280A13C0/WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe) as the following:

- Open CMD as administrator,
- Navigate to the folder that contains `WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe` (In my example I consider it in C:\ drive)
- Run the following command

> .\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe /i /gac

- Now Click on `AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe` to install the AppFabric patch.
- Reboot the server > Run SharePoint Installation again where the message error should not be listed again.

For more details check [Windows Server AppFabric is not correctly configured During installing SharePoint Server 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/06/14/windows-server-appfabric-is-not-correctly-configured-as-sharepoint-2013-prerequisites/)

Comment: I tried the steps suggested by you but still same error(AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1605) while running SharePoint Installation after reboot.

Comment: run the command with the following parameter .\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe /i CacheClient,CachingService,CacheAdmin /gac  then check result also please tell me are you run prerequisite as offline mode or online mode